# Git Reset - remotes/origin/master not in sync with local master

Tags: git, version-control, git-reset

On one of my repositories the local master is ahead of the remotes/origin/master

```
* - master (123)
* -
* - remotes/origin/master (456)
```

All my other local repos (based on the same remote repository) have the remote/origin/master at the same commit hash (123). How do I reset the local repo so the remotes/origin/master is back in sync?

Comment: do I get that right. On other checkouts remotes/origin/master points to commit 123?

Comment: @Reto yes. I may have reset the out-of-sync repo previously.

Comment: you manually checked the remote branch out (git checkout remotes/origin/master) and resetted it to another commit? (see my edit)

Comment: Have you changed some code on your local repo?

Comment: Please reword your problem/what you are looking for. I'm not sure if I understand it right.

Comment: @PierreMage nope - I have gone with reto's answer and just delete and re-added the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens if you do `git fetch origin`?

or if you have manually broken something with the remote branch you could always:

```
git remote -v # note url
git remote rm origin  
git remote add origin <url>
```

Comment: thanks, I removed and re-added the origin and it has fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

As Pierre pointed out you will "lose" your local modifications (if you have commited your changes they are still there as loose objects). So you might want to create a temporary branch before resetting

This will reset your local branch so it points to the same commit as the remote.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b old_master // optional 
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: WARNING: You will lose your local modifications, if any.

Comment: ah I missed this response. I will give this a go next time, thanks

Comment: xylar: If I understood you correctly this wouldnt be the soluation for your problem. This would have resetted the local 'master' branch back to your outdated remote branch