# remote/origin/master is ahead of master

Tags: git

I have a problem which is the reverse case of the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118295/head-master-ahead-of-origin-master) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838758/git-reset-remotes-origin-master-not-in-sync-with-local-master). My situation looks like this:

[image]

So, `remotes/origin/master` is ahead of `master`. When I issue `git status` I obtain:

```
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

However, I do not want to move or fast-forward `master` to `remote/origin/master`. Rather, I want `remotes/origin/master` to move back or rewind to where `master` currently is. All of the `Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index` has been backed up elsewhere so that after moving `remotes/origin/master` back to `master`, I can recreate the changes if needed. All of the changes currently in `remotes/origin/master` are not useful and can be discarded.

I tried the following:

`git branch -d babe82a3bb3efb71e6fdff38e40ec08fe691e5d6` in an attempt to achieve this rewind of `remotes/origin/master`. This gives error:

`error: branch 'babe82a3bb3efb71e6fdff38e40ec08fe691e5d6' not found.`

I then tried:

`git branch -d remotes/origin/master`, and this gives error:

`error: branch 'remotes/origin/master' not found.`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the actual goal here?  Do you want to also rollback the extra commit on the Git repository itself?

Comment: You could do `git push -f origin master` to force push your current branch to master.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, those change in `remotes/origin/master` are just flawed and to be discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `git branch -d remotes/origin/master` fails is simple enough: it's not a *branch*.  What it is, is a *remote-tracking name*, rather than a *branch* name.  It's often shown as just `origin/master`: Git is inconsistent about how much to remove from names like `refs/heads/master`, which becomes `master`, vs `refs/remotes/origin/master`, which becomes either `origin/master` or `remotes/origin/master` depending on whether Git feels like stripping off one component—`refs/`—or two, `refs/remotes/`.

Your Git—your software, working in/on your repository—creates or updates remote-tracking names based on what your Git gets from some other Git: some version of Git software working in/on some *other* repository.  That *other* repository has branch names, which find commits.  When you connect your Git to their Git, your Git gets from them any commits they have, that you don't, and then creates or updates your remote-tracking names to remember where their *branch* names go.

So, this means *their* branch named `master` identifies commit `babe82a3bb3efb71e6fdff38e40ec08fe691e5d6`.  Your own Git repository has this commit because you got it from their Git repository; your Git finds it using the name `origin/master`, as produced by changing `master` (their *branch* name) into `origin/master` (your remote-tracking name).

If you think their Git repository should move *their* branch name `master` back one step so as to forget `babe82a3bb3efb71e6fdff38e40ec08fe691e5d6`, and instead use whichever commit your own `master` specifies, you can use a forced `git push` operation to *command* them—their Git software on their repository—to do that.  Whether their Git will obey your Git's command is up to them.  Note that their commit may be in millions of other clones by now (depending on how popular *their* Git repository is).  If it's *only* in their repository, and you have permission to "rewind" their branches like this with `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease`, you'll be fine.

Comment: This worked out exactly. When I issued `git push --force` I obtained: `Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
 + babe82a...f599114 master -> master (forced update)` and then on going to the online repo, indeed there is no mention of the `babe82a...` commit/push.

Comment: Yes - the commit itself (babe82a...) might linger on the server for some time (especially noticeable on GitHub, where there are URLs you can use to find out: just visit some commit that you can find easily, then swap in the raw hash ID of the other one) but you won't *see* it, and other Gits getting commits from the Git at `origin` won't see it either.

Comment: There seems to be a size limit on private repositories on github. Would pushes such as `babe82a3bb3efb71e6fdff38e40ec08fe691e5d6` above, once they are "rewound", still continue to contribute to the limit? I would expect that once they are disassociated as above, they do not contribute to a user's upper size limit and they are routinely cleaned from the system and not occupy unnecessary space.

Comment: There are multiple size limits. The one most people hit first is on individual file sizes: GitHub do some extra GitHub-only checking of the size of each file ("blob", really) stored in each commit, and if any one file goes over 100 MB, they reject the commit entirely, so it never winds up in the repository at all. I'm not sure how one reaches the other size limits as I have never run into that myself. :-) If you find yourself hitting size limits that don't seem to make sense other than maybe the "removed" commit, you could contact the GitHub support folks.